# How to load multiple nii.gz files from a specific folder with python?

Tags: python, load, nifti

I have a folder in which I keep multiple `fmri` images in the format nii.gz to which I want to apply a preprocessing script and then save the altered data.

```py
# I tried to do something like:

    subj = 1
    folder_dir = r'C:\Users\myfolder'
    files = []
    for filename in os.listdir(folder_dir):
            img = nib.load(filename)
            data = img.get_fdata()
        
            ## Preprocessing code ##
        
        
            name=''+str(subj)+'.nii'
            final_im 
            final_im.save(name)
        
            subj += 1`
```

But I always get an error saying :

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [12], in <cell line: 13>()
     12 files = []
     13 for filename in os.listdir(folder_dir):
---> 14         img = nib.load(filename)
     15         data = img.get_fdata()
     17         ## Preprocessing code ##

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nibabel\loadsave.py:92, in load(filename, **kwargs)
     90     stat_result = os.stat(filename)
     91 except OSError:
---> 92     raise FileNotFoundError(f"No such file or no access: '{filename}'")
     93 if stat_result.st_size <= 0:
     94     raise ImageFileError(f"Empty file: '{filename}'")

FileNotFoundError: No such file or no access: 'firstfile_in_the_flder.nii.gz'
```

Comment: Are you running the script in that folder?  If not, you probably need to give nib.load the full pathname.  Something like: img = nib.load(folder_dir + '\' + filename)